# Angular 9 carousel ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

<carousel [isAnimated]="true" pauseOnFocus="true" showIndicators="false" ng-repeat="slide in slides" >

```
</slide>
<slide>
<img src="assets/img/2.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
</slide>
<slide>
<img src="assets/img/3.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
</slide>
<slide>
<img src="assets/img/4.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
</slide>
<slide>
<img src="assets/img/5.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
</slide>
```

I want to change indicators. is it possible to change the shape and position of indicators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style anything of the carousel in the way you want. Either having a specific bootstrap theme or just adding css for the bootstrap specific classes and add or overwrite styling. The important part here is that you need to have this be part of a global css sheet.

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

If you would want to move the indicators out of the actual carousel you could do:

```
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

If you would want to not display indicators at all you could do:

```
.carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}
```

Just play around with the css values to get to the result you want to achieve.

You might need to use `!important` on your css values to overwrite the existing ngx-bootstrap styling

Comment: thanks a lot. It works up to some level. Can't I get carousel indicators out of the image?

Comment: @AmindaAmarasinghe I have updated the answer according to your question

Comment: thank you very much @Jelle . I was successful in my task with your help.

Comment: Hi @AmindaAmarasinghe if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use !important just before ; sign in any CSS statement in global style page.